# React native custom radio buttons different colors for active button

Tags: react-native, radio-button, radio-group

I've been working with a package https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-custom-radio-group and have a requirement to get different colors (active) on selection of radio buttons. Lets say I've three buttons so , if first radio is selected then it should be of green, if second is selected it should be or red color and so on.

So basically I want their active class to work differently upon its selection. I've also gone through some documentation and also the RadioButton.style.js but couldnt find any proper help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: check the value on onChange event, if button == 1, set the buttonContainerActiveStyle color to green etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using the props provided in the package. Pass the value of the selected button to a callback function and change style of the button according to the value.

Here is the working demo: https://snack.expo.io/@cruz404/custom-radio-button

Example code:

```
export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state ={
          activeBgColor: "white",
          activeTxtColor: "black",
          inActiveBgColor: "white",
          inActiveTxtColor: "black",
      };
  }

  changeStyle(value) {
     if(value == "transport_car") {
        this.setState({
              activeBgColor: "red",
              activeTxtColor: "white",
              inActiveBgColor: "white",
              inActiveTxtColor: "black",
        });
     } else if(value == "transport_bike") {
        this.setState({
              activeBgColor: "blue",
              activeTxtColor: "white",
              inActiveBgColor: "white",
              inActiveTxtColor: "black",
        });
     } else if(value == "transport_bus") {
         this.setState({
               activeBgColor: "green",
               activeTxtColor: "white",
               inActiveBgColor: "white",
               inActiveTxtColor: "black",
         });
     }
 }

render () {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text> SELECT: </Text>
      <RadioGroup
            radioGroupList={radioGroupList}
            buttonContainerActiveStyle = {{backgroundColor: this.state.activeBgColor}}
            buttonTextActiveStyle = {{color: this.state.activeTxtColor}}
            buttonContainerInactiveStyle = {{backgroundColor: this.state.inActiveBgColor}}
            buttonTextInactiveStyle = {{color: this.state.inActiveTxtColor}}
            onChange={(value) => {this.changeStyle(value);}}
      />
    </View>);
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!